# How do I align this row with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to get an image to be in the same row as my text in my ABOUT section.

I've tried to wrap my `<div class="portrait">` and `<p>` into a `<div class="wrapper">` with css `flex-direction:row`

`Heres a pen:` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqRdjb

I think some CSS is being overwritten, or I'm not using my CSS properly.

Thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: What do you mean by the same row as your text? Can you post minimal reproducible code and something that indicates your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: row` has no effect without including `display: flex`.

Adjust the wrapper css to:

```
.wrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can also refactor the margins for the elements inside the wrapper if you want to center them. Any vertical margins can be removed and applied to the wrapper itself.

```
.portrait{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px; /* Align your image right */
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color:#555;
}

.ABOUT p{
  font-size:1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: auto; /* align text left */
}
```